# Format only selected code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting, eclipse-pdt

As the title says, I want to format only selected lines of code. I know by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>F</kbd> formats whole file.

Formatting whole file is not good options as it will create lots of conflicts when I will commit the file. I changed a portion of the file (copied some code from internet etc.).
Is there any easy way to format selected lines in `eclipse`. I have searched a lot but found no solution.
I am working with PHP.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Highlight (left click, drag, left release) the lines you want to format, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, or right click and select `Source -> Format`.

For Java code, you have to highlight a complete piece of code (statement(s), method).

For PHP, I imagine you would still have to highlight a complete piece of code.

Tested on Windows version of Eclipse 4.2.

Comment: This was first thing I tried, but it didn't worked for me. I am using eclipse version 3.7.2 platform ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @Anf: I didn't have any PHP on Eclipse handy at home.  Highlighting and formatting worked selectively on PHP on Windows Eclipse 3.6.

Comment: It does not work again on 4.5.1 (Mars) on OS X. Or is there any configuration for this behavior? (In case it is useful, I am working with Java.)

Comment: Oh, I figured out what happened. It is just not allowed to format only part of a javadoc block (e.g. only for `@param` tags). I can still format only a single documentation block anyway so not a big deal.